# Handle lengthy async tasks and notify user

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

Is there a Prism alternative to the class 'NotifyTaskCompletion' in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx

The class 'NotifyTaskCompletion' in the above article is used to handle async tasks, keeping the GUI responsive and notifying the views with results or with failure information.

It sounds like a good idea but I wonder if there is a more neat way to do the same thing using a Prism utility class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism does not have any equivalent to 'NotifyTaskCompletion' class.  However, you can use the class with Prism framework without any limitations.

Note also that Stephen Cleary has an updated version (NotifyTask)

https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.Mvvm.Async/1.0.0-pre-03

Answer (score 1):

No, Prism provides no equivalent type to handle asynchronous properties.

But you can implement your own `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>` class and use it in your Prism application if you want to. Or you can use the `NotifyTask<TResult>` class in [Mvvm.Async](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async). Neither does not break any kind of pattern or practice.

Properties are generally supposed to return a value immediately. Both [Mvvm.Async](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async) and [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI) provide asynchronous implementations of the `ICommand` interface.

[ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI) also has a concept of [output properties](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-models/) that you may want to check out. The view binds to the read-only output property which reflects the latest value that has been sent through an `IObservable` stream of values.